# Column will not sort in google spreadsheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I've been searching everywhere for this answer.

Here's my sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsdHK_HDz--odFE4cHFSeVNkYlhCRGI5OWJKdFEta3c#gid=0

Here's my form: 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/12OBYAlNHXCDaObACY2zD58suDqEnu3XS7YYVO3Vz044/viewform

I have a Google Spreadsheet that is being fed from a Google Form. The column I want to sort by is a "TimeStamp." That specific column is not being fed by the form, it is being fed from a custom function that watches column "N" and when a change is made to a row in column "N" column "L" is Timestamped.

To make my data usable, I need to sort by column "L" which is the "Date" that the person was last online. However, it is not allowing me to sort. Normally, I will right click on the column label "N" and do a sort, but it does not appear in the context menu. If I check "Data" at the stop, "Sort" is grayed out.

It seems that every column after "L" is not sortable either. Which is odd because "A-N" IS sortable (even though they're being fed by a form.

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure this out. Is it because of the function? I don't think so because then why would subsequent columns to "L" not be able to sort either?

Could use a little help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's precisely because your column `L` is not a part of the form responses that it can't be used as sort criteria. Try adding a non important question that you can overwrite with your own timeStamp, this one will be "part of the game" and will be useable to sort your sheet.
I tried this on a copy of your sheet and it seems to have no undesirable side effect.

That said, this is just a practical workaround, I have no sufficient knowledge about Google forms to know what are the "logic and rules" that Google applies in form/spreadsheet links.
I used to work with forms quite a while ago (first version) but now I tend to prefer designing forms in webapps to keep more freedom in the process.

Comment: thanks. If you consider the answer is valid please consider accepting it.